# Longest non-decreasing monotonic subsequence c++

Tags: c++, vector, max, sequence

I need to write a program which find the longest non-decreasing subsequence in a sequence of numbers from *-10* to *10<sup>5</sup>*, so for example if my input is:

> 6 6 6 2 2 7

My program will return *4*, cause of:

> 6 6 6 7

If my input is:

> 100 6 6 6 2 2 7

My half-way working code will return a *4* as it should.

But if my input is:

> 100 110 120 6 6 6 2 2 7

My program returns *3*, cause of

> 100 110 120

But it should again return *4*. I really can't track where it goes wrong:

```
int FindIndex(std::vector<int> &v, int k, int result, int key) {
    while (result-k > 1) {
        int mid = k + (result-k)/2;
        if (v[mid] >= key)
            result = mid;
        else
            k = mid;
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    int n=0;

    while(cin >> n) {
        vector<int> v;
        int cur;
        while (cin >> cur) {
            v.push_back(cur);
            if (cin.get() == '\n') {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (v.size() == 0)
            return 0;

        vector<int> holder(v.size(), 0);
        int length = 1; 

        holder[0] = v[0];
        for (size_t i = 1; i < v.size(); i++) {
            if (v[i] < holder[0])
                holder[0] = v[i];
            else if (v[i] >= holder[length-1])
                holder[length++] = v[i];
            else
                holder[FindIndex(holder, -1, length-1, v[i])] = v[i];
        }
        cout  << length << endl;
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Why should `6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 7` return `6, 6, 6, 7`?  The 2's in the middle should break the increasing sequence.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code, line by line, in a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard problem because you're not enforcing adjacency, only order. Meaning that you cannot simply take the first element and assume that testing it will find the answer (as your code is currently doing.)

We can solve this in *O(n log(n))* through [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming): We'll start from the end, and calculate the longest increasing sequence for each number. For example given an input set: `vector<int> v` we can store the longest increasing sequence in `vector<int> dynamicTable(size(v))` We can then populate that as follows:

```
for(int i = size(v) - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j < size(v); ++j) {
        if(v[i] <= v[j]){
            dynamicTable[i] = max(dynamicTable[j], dynamicTable[i]);
        }
    }
    ++dynamicTable[i];
}
```

Once `dynamicTable` has been populated like this you can find your "Longest Non-Decreasing Monotonic Sub-Sequence" like this:

```
*max_element(cbegin(dynamicTable), cend(dynamicTable))
```

Note that this expects that your input array was non-empty and correspondingly `dynamicTable` was non-empty.)

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/ZZ17gE)

Comment: Thanks a lot , needed a little bit edit , cause this doesn't compile on gcc ,  I get it now how its work , too bad this wasn't explained properly which lead to my question :)

Comment: This looks like O(N^2).

Comment: @DavidsAmause Good news the Live Example links all use gcc, you might look at those. As far as proper explanation what can I do to help explain?